# Print chi square statistic with table in R

Tags: r

My dataset looks like this (with about 200+ variables):

```
intervention<-c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
age_group<-c("17-24 years","25-55 years","17-24 years","17-24 years","25-55 years", "25-55 years")
gender<-c("male","male","female","female","male","female")
marital_status<-c("partnered","single","single","partnered","partnered","single")
education<-c("high school","university","university","university","high school","university")
df<-data.frame(intervention,age_group,gender,marital_status,education)
```

I used the `tableone` package to put this into a table stratified by intervention:

```
listVar_Int<-c("age_group","gender","marital_status","education")
catVar_Int<-c("intervention", "age_group","gender","marital_status","education")
Table_int<-CreateTableOne(vars = listVar_Int, data = df, factorVars = catVar_Int, strata = c("intervention"))
```

When I print it (`print(Table_int, nonnormal = biomarkers, exact = "stage", quote = TRUE, noSpaces = TRUE, showAllLevels = TRUE)` ), the table looks like this (table from my actual dataset):

```
                                      Stratified by Intervention group
                                          1           2           3           p test    
n                                         127         122         125              
age_group (%)                                                                 0.713
 17-24 years                             42 (33.3)   33 (27.7)   39 (31.5)  
 25-55 years                             60 (47.6)   60 (50.4)   67 (54.0)                  
gender (%)                                                                    0.047
 Male                                     49 (38.9)   59 (49.2)   71 (57.7)  
 Female                                   54 (42.9)   43 (35.8)   34 (27.6)
```

Based on what I've read, the default test is the `chisq.test`. Is there a way to print the chi square test statistic so that it shows up alongside the p test?

Comment: I did not see an easy way using the avaialble parameters. Thgere is a parameter that lets you change the test from chi-square to Kruskal-Wallis, but even that one will not print a statistic. Your request seems very reasonable given current statistical practice in the medical literature, but I think you would need to hack the print.TableOne function (which is where the "test" is calculated as you apparently already understand.)

Comment: First comment has error in th.at nonnorm test for categorical is not Kruskal-Wallis but rather the fisher.test.

Comment: After looking at the flow of data in the print.TableOne function it seems that your add-test modification would need to be done on the code of whereever getAnywhere(print.CatTable) sends the column summary data, since print.TableOne sequentially passes the column names to a hidden generic print` function implicitly determined by their class assigned by the CreateTableOne function. The R logic seems distributed in a fairly complex manner that I haven't yet decoded and is not documented at the code level. Probably need to extract the entire package to see if there are helpful comments in source.

Comment: @IRTFM I appreciate your help. I'm still quite new to R so I thought I'd ask anyways. Right now, the only way I can think of without it getting too complicated is to use `chisq.test(df$intervention, df$age_group, correct = F)` on my variables and just add the extra column after exporting to excel. However, it's a bit difficult for me to get a statistic if I am stratifying by two variables instead of one. Any recommendations?

Comment: Why not use the `interaction` function for the stratification variables? (You do realize, i hope, that "real statisticians" will look at such a table and deem your use of both p-values and chi-square calculations as totally redundant.)